# Electron Forge packaging configuration not working

Tags: electron-forge

I am trying to package my app with `electron-forge package` using the following configuration:

```
"config": {
  "forge": {
    "make_targets": {
      "linux": [
        "deb"
      ],
      "win32": [
        "squirrel"
      ]
    },
    "electronPackagerConfig": {
      "asar": false,
      "dir": "./src",
      "platform": [
        "linux",
        "win32"
      ],
      "arch": [
        "ia32",
        "x64"
      ],
      "ignore": [
        ".idea"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The version of `electron-forge` I am using is 3.0.1.

Only the values `asar` and `ignore` are recognized, while `dir`, `platform` and `arch` are ignored. I do not see an error and would highly appreciate help, a hint or a link to any working example.

---

**Update:**

It has since been suggested [here](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-forge/issues/177) to use the command line for providing these options.

While

```
electron-forge package --arch=ia32,x64 --platform=win32,linux
```

does package the app for all the specified systems, although the output looks like this:

```
✔ Checking your system
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: ia32,x64
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: armv7l <-- ???
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
✔ Preparing to Package Application for arch: x64
✔ Compiling Application
✔ Preparing native dependencies
✔ Packaging Application
```

It does not seems to actually be packaging the app for the `armv7l` architecture as it says there, I think that this is just a bug with the console output, the results in the output directory look good.

Anyway.. providing the packaging options via command line does not solve my initial problem, because I still can not specify the `dir` option for `electron-packer` that way. So, while the documentation for [`electronPackagerConfig`](https://beta.electronforge.io/config/electronPackagerConfig) suggests all options for `electron-packer` can be set with this configuration object:

> This config object provides options directly to electron-packager, the tool we use to package your app behind the scenes.

And while `electron-forge package --help` says I can set the current working directory after the options:

```
Usage: electron-forge-package [options] [cwd]
```

Which is actually not the case, this just simply sets the `out` directory where everything is written to.

I am still stuck with this. Is there any way to provide the `dir` option via `electron-forge`? If not, my suggestion to the developers of `electron-forge` would be to implement the configuration for this in a way that makes my initial configuration from above work, because I think this is an intuitive way to configurate these parameters, using the command line to override them could still be an option, I guess.

Comment: Since my problem with all this is that unwanted directories get packaged into the final app, I am currently using
`ignore` as a workaround. This is not really a satisfying solution, as I want to set all options for `electron-packager`
with the corresponding configuration object (i.e. `electronPackagerConfig`), especially the `dir` option for the source
directory, but for now I will just stick with `ignore` until a better solution arrives.